# Does this tool exist: Literature search citation filter?

Tags: research-process, literature-search

I'm wondering if a tool/website to do a specific task exists:

Suppose I have a set of papers (which we'll say for simplicity are hosted on the arxiv), S. I want to keep track of all the papers that are posted on the Arxiv that cite any element of S. Ideally I could then see the papers in chronological order such that I make sure I don't miss anything.

The idea is that S contains the seminal/landmark papers in my field, which are almost always cited by new papers in this field. The hope is that I'll be able to more easily surf the arxiv and not let new paper slip past me.

Before I decide whether or not I want to devote some energy to building such a tool, I'm wondering if it already exists, or if even a hacky solution exists.

Comment: Would Google Scholar citation alerts work, or is it too limited for your usecase? (E.g. Google Scholar sometimes misses citations, and is somewhat slow to pick them up in my experience.)

Comment: This seems to do what I want. It seems I can only create notifications for one paper at a time (as opposed to a set of papers), but that's probably okay. 

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question, as far as I have understood, say you are interested in that paper and that paper is cited by new papers, if that case, academia.edu have that function I receive updates about I paper I have read and interested and that keep me updated. If doesn't case, could you please elaborate more.